# iOS TableView With One Cell, Stay at Bottom?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview that has, and will always have, just one cell.  I would like this cell to be located at the bottom of the view's frame, but am unsure how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.  The Table View has an .xib attached to it, and is grouped, with 1 section and one cell.

Comment: Short answer, it will have other content in the same view, that I would like to be above the cell.  The table view will parse an xml containing one item.  The xml is located online and will change frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drag a table view into your xib's regular view, and have its view controller implement the `<UITableViewDataSource>` and `<UITableViewDelegate>` protocols.  Then, you can drag the table view to any position you choose within your xib.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a tableView :)

You should use a textView (or anything you need) and if you want to make it look like a tableView, you can set the background of the view and add rounded corners to your subView. I think you should make it look like a tableView, but you should not use one. You can also add a scrollView to make it even more alike.